# Is this implementation for token based authentication in flask-peewee secure and efficient?

Tags: python, angular.js, flask

I'm making an app with a Flask API backend using a Flask-Peewee ORM and an AngularJS frontend.

The Flask-Peewee ORM doesn't support token based authentication, so I decided to try to implement this myself. This is quite a bit beyond what I usually do, and I have in fact no idea whether this is secure or not. It does work, but that's all I know. Any feedback, from pointing out obvious security flaws to advice on good practices, is more than welcome.

This is my implementation:

### Models

I made an extra model for the api-key:

```
class APIKey(db.Model):
    key = CharField()
    secret = CharField()
    user = ForeignKeyField(User)
```

### Controllers

I made controllers for logging in, logging out, and registration. These all return a response, which is then used by AngularJS. Basically, it creates an APIKey on succesful login and destroys all APIkeys related to the user on logout.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    try:
        key = request.json["key"]
        secret = request.json["secret"]
        print "Key and secret delivered"
        try:
            user = User.select().join(APIKey).where(APIKey.key == key, APIKey.secret == secret).get()
            print "APIKey found"
            return jsonify ({"success" : True, "user_id" : user.id})
        except: #key and secret were invalid
            print "Key and secret invalid"
            return jsonify({"success" : False, "reason" : "key invalid"})
    except KeyError: # no key delivered, check for any existing keys for the user, if not, create one
        try: #check whether a username and password were delivered
            username = request.json["username"]
            password = request.json["password"]
            print "Username and password found"
            user = User.get(User.username == username)
            print "Username exists"
            if user.check_password(password): #if the user exists and the password is correct
                print "Password correct"
                key = urandom(50).encode('hex')
                secret = urandom(50).encode('hex')
                key_secret = APIKey.get_or_create(key = key, secret = secret, user = user)
                return jsonify ({"success" : True, "user_id" : user.id, "key" : key, "secret" : secret})
            else: #the user exists, but the password is incorrect
                return jsonify ({"success" : False, "reason" : "Password incorrect"})
        except (User.DoesNotExist, KeyError): #the user does not exist
            return jsonify ({"success" : False, "reason" : "User does not exit"})

@app.route('/logout', methods=['POST'])
def logout():
    key = request.json["key"]
    secret = request.json["secret"]
    try:
        user = User.select().join(APIKey).where(APIKey.key == key, APIKey.secret == secret)
        api_keys = APIKey.delete().where(APIKey.user == user)
        api_keys.execute()
        return jsonify({"success" : True, "key_removed" : True})
    except APIKey.DoesNotExist:
        return jsonify({"success" : True, "key_removed" : False})

@app.route('/join', methods=['POST'])
def join():
    user_to_join = request.json
    user = User(username = user_to_join["username"], email = user_to_join["email"])
    user.set_password(user_to_join["password"])
    user.save()
    return jsonify ({"success" : True})
```

I also modified the [APIKeyAuthentication class](https://github.com/coleifer/flask-peewee/blob/master/flask_peewee/rest.py#L42) to work with the token:

```
class APIKeyAuthentication(Authentication):
    """
    Requires a model that has at least two fields, "key" and "secret", which will
    be searched for when authing a request.
    """
    key_field = 'key'
    secret_field = 'secret'

    def __init__(self, auth, model, protected_methods=None):
        super(APIKeyAuthentication, self).__init__(protected_methods)
        self.model = model
        self._key_field = model._meta.fields[self.key_field]
        self._secret_field = model._meta.fields[self.secret_field]

    def get_query(self):
        return self.model.select()

    def get_key(self, k, s):
        try:
            return self.get_query().where(
                self._key_field==k,
                self._secret_field==s
            ).get()
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    def get_key_secret(self):
        for search in [request.headers, request.args, request.form]:
            if 'key' in search and 'secret' in search:
                return search['key'], search['secret']
        return None, None

    def authorize(self):
        if request.method not in self.protected_methods:
            return True

        key, secret = self.get_key_secret()
        try:
            g.user = User.select().join(APIKey).where(APIKey.key == key, APIKey.secret == secret).get()
            return g.user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return False
```

### Front-end

In Angular, I do the following:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        if (localStorageService.get('key') == undefined)
        {
            $rootScope.logged_in = false;
            $scope.openLoginWindow();
        }
        else
        {
            $rootScope.key = localStorageService.get('key');
            $rootScope.secret = localStorageService.get('secret');
            $http.post('/login', {"key" : $rootScope.key, "secret" : $rootScope.secret})
            .success(function(response){
                if (response.success)
                {
                $rootScope.user_id = response.user_id;
                $rootScope.$broadcast("key_set");
                $rootScope.logged_in = true;

                [...further code while logged in ...]
```

If the user is not logged in, they will be taken to a login window (this app is for logged-in users only), that posts the username and password as follows:

```
$scope.login = function(){
        $http.post('/login', $scope.user_to_login)
        .success(function(response){
            if (response.success)
            {
                $rootScope.key = response.key;
                $rootScope.secret = response.secret;
                $rootScope.user_id = response.user_id;
                $rootScope.$broadcast("key_set");
                if ($scope.user_to_login.remember)
                {
                    localStorageService.add('key', $rootScope.key);
                    localStorageService.add('secret', $rootScope.secret);
                }
                $modalInstance.close(response);
            }
            else
            {
                ///
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: If you need to get a resource from the service later on, do you post the userid, the secret and key or only the key to the server?

Comment: @erik both key and secret are used to authenticate to the API; userid is unnecessary because the key is linked to the user in the database through APIKey.user.

Answer (score 1):

A short review:

- I havent spotted anything inherently insecure or inefficient
- It behooves you to check that the generated `key` and `secret` were not already assigned to a different user (it does not matter that the odds are astronomically low)
- The below should probably return `"success": False`

  ```
  except APIKey.DoesNotExist:
    return jsonify({"success" : True, "key_removed" : False})
  ```
- Since you use `api_keys` only once, you could replace the below with a oneliner. Also, in this case, `api_keys` is a terrible name

  ```
  api_keys = APIKey.delete().where(APIKey.user == user)
  api_keys.execute()
  ```

  becomes

  ```
   APIKey.delete().where(APIKey.user == user).execute()
  ```